# Accessing data in a many to many and one to many relations

Tags: php, yii

I don`t know howto accessing data from a related table (with ActiveRecords) and use all those records as a dataSource for a CActiveDataProvider. The main idea is that a user must be able to`CRUD` only the courses from his classes.

I have the following tables:

```
user (id, name, age, email...),
user_class (user_id, class_id),
class (id, name, description, ...),
course (id, class_id, name, description);
```

User and Class tables have a **MANY TO MANY** and Class and Course tables have a **ONE TO MANY** relation

I also defined the following relations:

User model relations:

```
'classes'=>array(
    self::MANY_MANY,
    'Class',
    'user_class(user_id, class_id)',
    ),
'courses'=>array(
    self::HAS_MANY,
    'Course',
    array('class_id','id'),
    'through'=>'classes'
)
```

Class model relations:

```
'users' => array(
    self::MANY_MANY,
    'User',
    'user_class(class_id, user_id)'
),
'courses' => array(
    self::HAS_MANY,
    'Class',
    'class_id'
),
```

Course model relations:

```
'class' => array(
    self::BELONGS_TO,
    'Class',
    'class_id'
)
```

In my `CourseController` , on `actionManage()` I have something like this:

```
public function actionManage() {
    $currentUser = User::model()->with('classes', 'courses')->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $userCourses = $currentUser->classes->courses; //--> NO courses!!!
    /* add users` courses to an CActiveDataProvider //--> how to do this?!
}
```

Comment: `$userCourses = $currentUser->classes->courses;` does not work because `$userCourses = $currentUser->classes` returns an array so there is no relation `courses`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `var_dump($currentUser->classes);` you'll notice that it's an array.

`$userCourses = $currentUser->classes[0]->courses;` will work if there are classes associated with `$currentUser`

Since you're loading many things lazily (each "class" loads its' "courses" the first time they're requested) this could become slow down the road, but for now, run with it I guess.

Comment: "this could become slow down the road" and how can I improve this? Any example/link will be great.